# Javascript regex match (random string in the middle)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test if a string can match a pattern in javascript

problem is there is a random string in the middle
pattern: "account/os/**some_random_string**/call_back"

so a string look like below will match

var mystring = "account/os/1234567/call_back"

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Are you looking for something like `/account\/os\/(.*)\/call_back/`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want a regex for starts with `account/os/` and ends with `/call_back`, here's one:

```
/^account\/os\/.*\/call_back$/
```

`.*` will match any random string (including the empty string.). If you want a minimum length on the random string you change the `*`:

```
.*    : 0 or more characters
.+    : 1 or more characters
.{n,} : n or more characters (replace n with an actual number)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends. If you want every single character between account/os/ and /call_back, use this:

```
var randomStr = mystring.match(/account\/os\/(.*)\/call_back/)[1];
```

The match will return an array with 2 elements, the first one with the entire match, the 2nd one with the group (.*). If you are completely sure that you have at least one character there, replace * with +.

If you know something more specific about the text you have to collect, here are some replacements for the .(dot is matching almost everything):

```
[A-z] for any of A, B, .. , Y, Z, a, b, .. , y, z
[0-9] for any digit
```

You can mix then and go fancy, like this:

```
[A-Ea-e0-36-8]
```

So, your pattern may look like this one:

```
/account\/os\/([A-Ea-e0-36-8]*)\/call_back/
```

Your example have a number there, so you are probably looking for:

```
/account\/os\/([0-9]*)\/call_back/
```

or

```
/account\/os\/(\d*)\/call_back/
```

.. it's the same thing.

Hope that helps.

Edit: What JS answer doesn't have a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/U2Jhw/